# Javascript on main navigation item to change div class when destination page is loaded

Tags: javascript, attr

I'm applying a function on one of my main navigation links, the function looks like this

```
    $(function() {
       $('#menu-item-1137').click(function(){
           $('#waterfacts').attr('class', 'active');
           $('li#simple2Tab').attr('class','active');    
       });  
    });
```

So my objective is very simple, when that item is clicked apply those class changes on the id elements.

The issue I'm facing is that the function works when you're already on destination page but let's suppose that I'm on site's index and then I click on that `#menu-item` the function will not work since I think it's trying to apply to the page I'm currently viewing.

So my question is, how do I do to tell the function to first wait until page is loaded and then run?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), and inside of that use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind the function to the element.

That will make it so the function will only apply after the page is loaded.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#menu-item-1137").on("click", function(){
        $('#waterfacts').attr('class', 'active');
        $('li#simple2Tab').attr('class','active'); 
    });

});​
```

Comment: Hey Ajak, thanks for your answer! could you please show me an example of your proposed code using my base please? I'm really struggling here. Not a javascript expert at all, sorry :/

Comment: Hi AJak, thank you for your code!!! I'm getting an error though trying to apply it the error in this case is: `Uncaught SyntaxError:Unexpected token ILLEGAL` not sure honestly what could it means. I pasted the code as it is to avoid errors.

Comment: What version of jquery are you running? Above 1.7? I've created a simple fiddle, to show how it works. Might help http://jsfiddle.net/GQxvE/

Comment: I just rewrote the code and I'm not getting the error, but I'm still having my original issue, the page loads and the function is not running. It works if I'm in the destination page but if I'm on any other page it will not wait until destination is loaded. Sorry friend, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You already bind the event after the DOM is loaded, because of the shortcut

```
$(function() {})
```

which is equivalent to

```
$(document).ready(function() {})
```

[jQuery .ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Do you change/insert your menue dynamically after the initial loading of the page?
If so, you have to apply the event after that.

You can easily debug problems like this by checking if your element is in the DOM before binding the events:

```
$(function() {
    console.log($('#menu-item-1137').length);
    $('#menu-item-1137').click(function(){
       $('#waterfacts').attr('class', 'active');
       $('li#simple2Tab').attr('class','active');    
   });
});
```

If your output on the console shows a zero, your element is not in the DOM yet and the event will not be binded.
To help you in this case, we need more information about the structure of your site.